# How to disable display of authoring information in drupal?

Tags: drupal-6, themes

Am doing a local website in drupal.
I have applied the theme 'Acquia Marina' (http://drupal.org/node/315555) to it.

Under Administer > Themes > Configure
I have unchecked "Enable or disable the *submitted by Username on date* text when displaying posts of the following type" for type 'Page' and the same is enabled for 'Story' (I don't have my own content types yet)

But I still get the *submitted by Username on date* text on the all the 'page's

I have tried, clearing performance cache, trying all(4) combinations on the checkboxes in question, but to no avail. But this setting works perfectly in the default theme.

I guess its some behaviour of the theme which I need to override. But have no clue.

Any suggestions?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

go to index.php?q=admin/build/themes/settings/acquia_marina, > "Theme-specific settings" > "Acquia Marina settings" > **expand** "Node settings" (that's what i missed at first) > "Author & date", and disable authorname and date, either for all content types, or for specific ones.

Answer (score 5):

If it would help to anyone, the authoring information can be disabled at each content type setting under: "admin/structure/types/manage/your_content_type" > Display setting and uncheck the "Display author and date information.". Another alternative is to set in node.tpl.php the condition "" to "".

Answer (score 1):

Simply cut out the template.

```
<?php print $submitted; ?>
```